# How to get SOAP Body in the interceptor in Mule ESB?

Tags: soap, mule, jax-ws, esb, mule-esb

ClientSide

```
 <cxf:jaxws-client
                        serviceClass="org.example.MyService"
                        port="MyServicePort"
                        operation="MyOperation">
                    <cxf:inInterceptors>
                        <spring:bean class="org.example.MyInInterceptor"/>
                    </cxf:inInterceptors>
                </cxf:jaxws-client>
```

How to get the SOAPBody from the SOAP response in the Interceptor below?

```
public class MyInInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    public MyInInterceptor() {

        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage cxfSoapMessage) throws Fault {

         SOAPMessage soapMessage = cxfSoapMessage.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);
        System.out.println("soapMessage ===> " + soapMessage);  
           }
```

}

Comment: What would you want to do with the soap body? Is this justfor logging or do you intend to do some data formatting? And what output are you getting from your current code?